# How to have one process listen to a serial port that another process is writing to?

Tags: bash, python, serial-port

I have a process (in bash) that writes data to a serial port. I would like to see that data, but instead of hooking up an Arduino and showing the data on a display, I thought it would be easier to just have another process read that serial port (e.g. in Python). This however presents a few problems:

1. Unless I actually connect a physical device, the port doesn't exist (Ubuntu).
2. Apparently, if one process is writing to that serial port, no other process is allowed to access that port for reading.

I *could* use a USB-to-USB cable to connect two USB ports together, but I would prefer if this could be solved in software -- a "virtual" connection, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the same serial port wouldn't work anyway, because you would be reading data that is sent by the *remote* end of the serial line, not what's sent locally. (Serial ports have two ends – they do not reflect data like mirrors.)

Do what terminal emulator programs do, and create a *pseudo-terminal* (pty) device. Your listener needs to open the "pty master" device `/dev/ptmx` and a pseudo-tty under `/dev/pts/*` will be automatically allocated, which the other process can use exactly like a serial port.

In Python, calling `fd1, fd2 = os.openpty()` will give you file descriptors for both ends of the pty and `os.ttyname(fd2)` will return the corresponding pty name. At this point, read from fd1 to receive all data that the other process writes to the pty.

In shell, you can use `socat -dd pty stdio`.

Alternatively: Run the other process under `strace` to monitor the actual kernel "write" calls being made, including their data.

If the process doesn't check carefully, you can just give it the path to a regular file instead of a tty device, and have all data stored in that file.